# R loop to assign various dates to loop defined objects and avoid eval(parse)

Tags: r

New to coding in R.
I would love to make this code more efficient and avoid the use of eval(parse). Currently I'm creating a ton of Value objects that I'm sure could be better laid out in a vector or matrix.

Input: User defined date YYYYMM; example 201712

```
iEval_YYYYMM <- '201712'
```

Desired Output: 2 format types (A,B); 3 years descending based on user input

```
Value Objects:
A.RP0Y0 = '01-Jan-17'
B.RP0Y0 = '2017-01'
A.RP0Y1 = '01-Jan-16
B.RP0Y1 = '2016-01'
...
A.RP1Y0 = '01-Dec-16'
B.RP1Y0 = '2016-12'
...
A.RP1Y3 = '01-Dec-14'
B.RP1Y3 = '2014-12'
```

I'm able to create all of the Value objects that I like, but I know this is not nice code and I'd like to avoid the eval(parse).
My current code:

```
iEval_Dt <- ymd(paste(iEval_YYYYMM,'01',sep='')) #reformat user input to date

l.name = c('RP0','RP1') #lag name vector
l.val = c(0,1) #lag value (months) vector
rp = c('Y0','Y1','Y2') #Rolling period vector

i = 1
j = 1
for(i in 1:length(l.name)) {
  for(j in 1:length(rp)) {

  b <- paste(l.name[i],rp[j],sep='')

  assign(b,iEval_Dt %m-% months(11 + l.val[i] + (j-1)*12)) #begin date of RP
  assign(paste('A.',b,sep=''),format(eval(parse(text=b)),'%Y-%m')) #formatA
  assign(paste('B.',b,sep=''),format(eval(parse(text=b)),'%d-%b-%y')) #formatB
  }
}
```

Any tips on how to make this code cleaner and a better method of storing so many value objects would be appreciated!

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should start you down a better road. Don't try to store everything in separate objects - that leads to you `eval(parsing())` names that you've `paste`d together - which is really difficult to work with. Just put everything in a data frame:

```
library(lubridate)
start = ymd(20171201)

lags = 0:1
years = 0:2

results = expand.grid(lags = lags, years = years)
results$date = start - months(results$lags) - years(results$years)

results$A = format(results$date, "%d-%b-%y")
results$B = format(results$date, "%Y-%m")

results
#   lags years       date         A       B
# 1    0     0 2017-12-01 01-Dec-17 2017-12
# 2    1     0 2017-11-01 01-Nov-17 2017-11
# 3    0     1 2016-12-01 01-Dec-16 2016-12
# 4    1     1 2016-11-01 01-Nov-16 2016-11
# 5    0     2 2015-12-01 01-Dec-15 2015-12
# 6    1     2 2015-11-01 01-Nov-15 2015-11
```

Now, instead of a cryptic `A.RP1Y0` you can use a more meaningful `with(results, A[lags == 1 & years == 0])`. And if you need the labels like `Y0`, `Y1`, etc, `paste` them in to a new column!

I don't think I precisely duplicated your logic, but you should be able to get it to work based off this example.

Comment: This worked beautifully and was exactly what I was looking for - thank you! I created a data frame _tDates_ and later called on this data frame to find/replace in a long character object (for use in a SQL query).

Answer (score 0):

My full code for anyone interested or anyone to make suggestions:

```
library(lubridate)
iEval_YYYYMM <- readline(prompt="Enter evaluation month YYYYMM: ")
lag  <- c(0,1,3)
rp <- 0:2

tDates  <- expand.grid(lag = lag, rp = rp)
tDates$ID <- paste('RP',tDates$lag,'Y',tDates$rp,sep = '')

tDates$sDt <- iEval_Dt - months(11 + tDates$lag + tDates$rp * 12)
tDates$eDt <- tDates$sDt + months(12) - days(1)

tDates$sDt.EQ <- format(tDates$sDt,'%Y-%m')
tDates$sDt.CQ <- format(tDates$sDt,'%d-%b-%y')

tDates$eDt.EQ <- format(tDates$eDt,'%Y-%m')
tDates$eDt.CQ <- format(tDates$eDt,'%d-%b-%y')

CQUpdate <- function(q) {
i <- 1
j <- 1
tmp <- q

for(i in 1:length(lag)) {
  for(j in 1:length(rp)) {
  # replace start dates for each rolling period
  find <- paste('<<s',tDates$ID[tDates$lag == lag[i] & tDates$rp == 
              rp[j]],'>>',sep='')
  replace <- tDates$sDt.CQ[tDates$lag == lag[i] & tDates$rp == rp[j]]
  tmp <- gsub(find,replace,tmp,fixed=TRUE)

  # replace end dates for each rolling period
  find <- paste('<<e',tDates$ID[tDates$lag == lag[i] & tDates$rp == 
              rp[j]],'>>',sep='')
  replace <- tDates$eDt.CQ[tDates$lag == lag[i] & tDates$rp == rp[j]]
  tmp <- gsub(find,replace,tmp,fixed=TRUE)

  # replace date for End of Month date of Evaluation Month (DD/MM/YYYY)
  tmp <- gsub('<<EOM>>',format(iEval_Dt + months(1) - 
             days(1),'%d/%m/%Y'),tmp,fixed=TRUE)

   }
 } 
tmp
}

#subtle change from prior - replaces with EQ formats
EQUpdate <- function(q) { 
i <- 1
j <- 1
tmp <- q

for(i in 1:length(lag)) {
  for(j in 1:length(rp)) {
  # replace start dates for each rolling period
  find <- paste('<<s',tDates$ID[tDates$lag == lag[i] & tDates$rp == 
              rp[j]],'>>',sep='')
  replace <- tDates$sDt.EQ[tDates$lag == lag[i] & tDates$rp == rp[j]]
  tmp <- gsub(find,replace,tmp,fixed=TRUE)

  # replace end dates for each rolling period
  find <- paste('<<e',tDates$ID[tDates$lag == lag[i] & tDates$rp == 
              rp[j]],'>>',sep='')
  replace <- tDates$eDt.EQ[tDates$lag == lag[i] & tDates$rp == rp[j]]
  tmp <- gsub(find,replace,tmp,fixed=TRUE)

  # replace Eval month year and month
  tmp <- gsub('<<YYYY>>',substr(iEval_YYYYMM,1,4),tmp,fixed=TRUE)
  tmp <- gsub('<<MM>>',substr(iEval_YYYYMM,5,6),tmp,fixed=TRUE)

   }
 } 
tmp
}
```